# angular version update 15 to 16 issue with dependencies

Tags: angular

I want to update my angular project version from 15 to 17 for achieve this I try to update to version 16 first. I use the below commands:

ng update @angular/core@16 @angular/cli@16

ng update @angular/cdk@16.2.13

ng update @angular/material @angular/cli

npm i

npm i -D @types/node@latest

after updating all versions to 16 when running my project I got the error:

[image]

[image]
**first, I want to run the project in version 16 and then update it to 17. What should I do**?

Comment: could you try upgrading `npm install ngx-markdown marked@^9.0.0 --save` markdown library?

Comment: now i get some new error: export type * from "MarkedOptions";

Comment: please share that screenshot also in the question!

Comment: I put it in question

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting node_modules and reinstall dependencies with command `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. I think this should solve your issue.

Comment: it does not work